# UICollectionView wrapped in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that I placed in a custom `UIViewController` via Storyboard and pinned its leading/trailing/top/bottom space to its superview.

Then I have a custom `UICollectionViewController` subclass that should use the collection view. So in the superview's `UIViewController` (PrimaryViewController) I have an outlet to the collection view and I instantiate my custom `UICollectionViewController`. I assign it the collection view and I assign the custom UICollectionViewController as delegate and dataSource for the collection view.

But when I run this, the collection view doesn't appear on the screen. It is obvious that the `viewDidLoad()` doesn't get called in the custom `UICollectionViewController` class so either I'm missing a key part or I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Can somebody tell me how to construct the connection between the collection view (which is placed via Storyboard) and the custom `UICollectionViewController` class (which is code only) in a way that makes this work properly?

Here's my (simplified) code so far ...

```
class PrimaryViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var _collectionView:UICollectionView!
    private var _collectionViewCtrl:CustomCollectionViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _collectionViewCtrl = CustomCollectionViewController(collectionView: _collectionView)
    }
}


class CustomCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController {
    init(collectionView:UICollectionView) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.collectionView = collectionView
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not embed the `CustomCollectionViewController` in the `PrimaryViewController` IB. You can add a `UICollectionViewController` to the `UIViewController` and then change it's class to your custom class.

Comment: @thelaws The reason for this is that there is also a toolbar in my PrimaryViewController's view, not only the collection view alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IB or your Storyboard, you can use a container view and embed your custom collection view controller inside. This gives you the ability to manipulate each view controller in it's own context, because they each have their own `nib`, and will handle instantiating your collection view controller auto-magically.

Your `PrimaryViewController` can look like this:

```
class PrimaryViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak _collectionView: UIView
    private var _collectionViewController: CustomCollectionViewController! {
        // ???: You can also iterate through child view controllers looking for a class match if you embed other controllers.
        return self.childViewControllers[0] as CustomCollectionViewController!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Which will also call `viewDidLoad()` on your `CustomCollectionViewController`. You can hide and show the view through the `_collectionView` property, or directly manipulate it through `_collectionViewController`.

The pain comes from any logic that may be the appearance logic (`viewWillAppear(_: Bool)`, `viewWillDisappear(_: Bool)`, etc) because you'll have to trigger those yourself.

Your storyboard should look something like this (My container view is hidden):

[image: Storyboard example]

Comment: I will try this! I didn't know a CollectionViewController can be used in a Container, I thought only UIViews. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the object that acts as the delegate/datasource for a `UICollectionView` does not have to be derived from `UICollectionViewController`.  In fact, it shouldn't be unless you dragged out a UICollectionViewController in storyboard.

The datasource/delegate class should be derived from `NSObject`

```
@interface CustomCollectionViewSupervisor : NSObject <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

and must implement the datasource/delegate methods, including but not necessarily limited to

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: That however doesn't solve my problem that the collection view is not appearing. When I comment out the line _collectionViewCtrl = CustomCollectionViewController(collectionView: _collectionView) the collectionView appear properly. So this means that the custom collectionViewController has something to do with the collection view not appearing.